# Flutter, Hive is not displaying data once app started eventhough it has the data

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

**Once I press the + button I want to add Text: value to the screen and save it permenatly. But is is saving the all the value text but once I restart the app it is not displaying it. PLEASE HELPP!**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox('mytasks');
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State {
```

**ALL THE DATA SHOLD BE SAVED INSIDE THIS TASKS**

```
 var tasks = [];
  final Box box = Hive.box('mytasks');
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Hive.box('mytasks');
    //ONCE APP INITIALIZED IT WILL PRINT THE VALUE TO THE TERMINAL
    print(box.get('task'));
  }
```

HERE IT GETS THE DATA

```
  void addData() async {
    await box.put('task', tasks);
    box.values.toList();
    print(box.get('task'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('To do app'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: tasks.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(title: Text('${tasks[index]}'));
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            tasks.add('value');
          });
          return addData();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting any log for print statement in initState method

Comment: yes, so that I will be able to see the data inside my box once app restarted

Comment: have you found any solution , having th same issue here , data won't persist in the box

Comment: Yes I did, Inside the ListView builder I just changed item count: box.values.length it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a list to the Hive Box, you can add it with the `.addAll()` method and then get it with the `.values.toList()` method. If that doesn't work, revisit the `Hive.initFlutter()` method.

```
 void addData() async {
    await box.addAll(tasks);
    print(box.values.toList().toString());
  }
```

Comment: oh, it actually did the job but once I restart the app all the values keeps disappearing however all the values inside that mybox  exists but it can't display it to my screen

Comment: Then you can match the box values ​​back to the tasks list or put each value with a special key and call it with that key. You must have an error getting the value.